# Activity dando crash

Tags: java, android

Quando inicio a Activity "Dados" a tela fica branca o programa dá um crash, mas se comento toda a programação da mesma o programa não crasha, porém a tela fica em branco e o que está no .xml não aparece. O que estou fazendo de errado e como devo fazer para dar certo?

Botão da Activity anterior que inicia a Activity "Dados":

```
next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
    intentNext = new Intent(MenuInicial.this, Dados.class);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Float baseMt = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("baseM");
            intentNext.putExtra("baseM",baseMt);
            startActivity(intentNext);

        }
    });
```

Activity "Dados":

```
package com.mateus.ligacoestubulares;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Dados extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] AçoMontante = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
    String [] AçoBanzo = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
    String [] EspessuraT1 = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
    String [] EspessuraTo = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
    EditText campoFy1;
    EditText campoFyo;
    EditText campoT1;
    EditText campoTo;
    EditText normalM;
    EditText normalB;
    EditText momentoB;
    EditText teta;
    Button next;
    Intent intentNext;
    Bundle bundle;
    Double t1;
    Double to;
    Double f1;
    Double fo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados);

        Spinner spinnerMont = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerM);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoMontante);
        spinnerMont.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

        campoFy1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fy1);

        String fy1 = Double.toString(choiceM());

        campoFy1.setText(fy1);

        Spinner spinnerBanzo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerB);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoBanzo);
        spinnerBanzo.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

        campoFyo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fyo);

        String fyo = Double.toString(choiceB());

        campoFyo.setText(fyo);

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerT1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, EspessuraT1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter3);

        campoT1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);

        String espessura1 = Double.toString(choiceT1());

        campoT1.setText(espessura1);

        Spinner spinner0 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTo);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, EspessuraTo);
        spinner0.setAdapter(arrayAdapter4);

        campoTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);

        String espessura0 = Double.toString(choiceTo());

        campoTo.setText(espessura0);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
        intentNext = new Intent(Dados.this, ConferenciaDosDados.class);

        normalM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NormalM);
        normalB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NormalB);
        momentoB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Momento);
        teta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Teta1);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String normal = normalM.getText().toString();
                String normal1 = normalB.getText().toString();
                String momento = momentoB.getText().toString();
                String teta1 = teta.getText().toString();
                String resistenciaM = campoFy1.getText().toString();
                String resistenciaB = campoFyo.getText().toString();
                String espessuraM = campoT1.getText().toString();
                String espessuraB = campoTo.getText().toString();
                bundle.putString("NormalM",normal);
                bundle.putString("NormalB",normal1);
                bundle.putString("MomentB",momento);
                bundle.putString("Teta1",teta1);
                bundle.putString("fy1",resistenciaM);
                bundle.putString("fyo",resistenciaB);
                bundle.putString("t1",espessuraM);
                bundle.putString("to",espessuraB);
                intentNext.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intentNext);

            }
        });
    }

    public double choiceM() {

        if (AçoMontante.equals("SAE 1020")) {
            f1 = 250.0;
        } else if (AçoMontante.equals("E-155")) {
            f1 = 300.0;
        }
        return f1;
    }

    public double choiceB() {

        if (AçoBanzo.equals("SAE 1020")) {
            fo = 250.0;
        } else if (AçoBanzo.equals("E-155")) {
            fo = 300.0;
        }
        return fo;
    }

    public double choiceT1() {

        if (EspessuraT1.equals("0,75 mm")) {
            t1 = 0.75;
        } else if (EspessuraT1.equals("0,90 mm")) {
            t1 = 0.90;
        } else if (EspessuraT1.equals("0,95 mm")) {
            t1 = 0.95;
        }
        return t1;
    }

    public double choiceTo() {

        if (EspessuraTo.equals("0,75 mm")) {
            to = 0.75;
        } else if (EspessuraTo.equals("0,90 mm")) {
            to = 0.90;
        } else if (EspessuraTo.equals("0,95 mm")) {
            to = 0.95;
        }
        return to;
    }
}
```

xml da Activity "Dados":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dados"
                android:id="@+id/tituloDados"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Normal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/N"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/NormalM"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NormalB"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/No.Sd"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/NormalB"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/MomentoB"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/Mo.Sd"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Momento"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Angulo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/Teta"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/Teta1"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/f1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerM"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
            </Spinner>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="@string/fy1"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fy1"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:maxHeight="30dp"
                android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                android:background="#BCD2EE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fo"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerB"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
            </Spinner>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="@string/fyo"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fyo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:maxHeight="30dp"
                android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                android:background="#BCD2EE"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/T1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerT1"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
            </Spinner>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/t1"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/To"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerTo"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">
            </Spinner>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:maxHeight="30dp"
                    android:textColorHint="#838B8B"
                    android:background="#BCD2EE"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/botao1"
                android:id="@+id/prosseguir"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

LOG:

```
08-28 13:44:28.375 6764-6764/com.mateus.ligacoestubulares E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.mateus.ligacoestubulares, PID: 6764
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mateus.ligacoestubulares/com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
     at com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados.choiceM(Dados.java:125)
     at com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados.onCreate(Dados.java:46)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Seria interessante colocar o erro também.

Comment: Poste por favor o conteúdo do LogCat que aparece após o erro no app, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Temos alguns problemas aqui. Dentro do método `choiceM()` você está fazendo a verificação se o vetor `AçoMontante` é igual a uma string e sempre vai dar false nas duas condições, porque são tipos diferentes. Isso acarreta no outro problema, como você não inicializou a variável `f1`, ela está com valor `null` e você está retornando o valor `null` como parâmetro para o método `Double.toString()` e isso está fazendo seu app "crashar", pois `null` não pode ser convertido para `Double`.
Note que os mesmos problemas irão ocorrer nos métodos `choiceB()`, `choiceT1()` e `choiceTo()`.

**ATUALMENTE**

```
String [] AçoMontante = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
Double f1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String fy1 = Double.toString(choiceM());
    ...
}

public double choiceM() {

    if (AçoMontante.equals("SAE 1020")) {
        f1 = 250.0;
    } else if (AçoMontante.equals("E-155")) {
        f1 = 300.0;
    }
    return f1;
}
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
public double choiceM() {
    /* A primeira condição sempre vai ser true se você
       não estiver pensando em algo diferente desse
       tipo de verificação.
    */
    if (Arrays.asList(AçoMontante).contains("SAE 1020")) {
        f1 = 250.0;
    } else if (Arrays.asList(AçoMontante).contains("E-155")) {
        f1 = 300.0;
    } else {
        /* Você pode inicializar sua variável aqui,
           assim você sempre terá um valor para
           caso você precise processar a variável
        */
        f1 = 0.0;
    }
    return f1;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
08-28 13:44:28.375 6764-6764/com.mateus.ligacoestubulares E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.mateus.ligacoestubulares, PID: 6764
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mateus.ligacoestubulares/com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados.choiceM(Dados.java:125)
                                                                            at com.mateus.ligacoestubulares.Dados.onCreate(Dados.java:46)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Não use o Botão "Responder" para adicionar dados a pergunta, o campo de resposta é para colocar a solução apenas.